# width off all submenu LI's jquery

Tags: jquery, width, html-lists

How can i add the total width off all submenu li's to the submenu ul?

width()  method of jQuery?

```
<ul>
 <li>level 1</li>
 <li>
  <ul style="widht:150px;"> //total width children li / add width li's
   <li>level 2</li> //width 100
   <li>level 2</li> //width 50
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>level 1</li>
<li>
  <ul style="widht:150px;"> //total width children li / add width li's
   <li>level 2</li> //width 100
   <li>level 2</li> //width 50
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: are you sure you want to add all the width? Don't you want the width with the highest value ?

Comment: @jAndy - `<ul>` can be horizontal ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var Peek = 0;

$('ul ul').each(function(){    
   $(this).children('li').each(function(i, e){
      if($(e).outerWidth() > Peek)
         Peek = $(e).outerWidth();
   });

   $(this).width(Peek);
   Peek = 0;
});
```

which would set the sub uls width to the hightest width of the list items.

Comment: thnx, that works, is it also posible to put de highest width from the current ul? 

when i have 30 li the peek is very big