# Add <li> widths to parent <ul>

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I want to create a horizontal scroll gallery containing images.

i.e.

```
<ul class='fluid_ul'>
<li id='fluid_li'>
<img>
</li>
<li... etc etc
</ul>
```

The img's are a percentage height/auto width. The `li` also have a margin-right for spacing.

Because of this the width I need the UL to be changes when the window is resized/loaded.

I found this [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3061345/1097558) which looked promising but cannot get it to work at all in this context.

Any ideas/help for how to generate the UL width when the images resize would be amazing!

Comment: If you make the ul `display: inline-block` it will mean that it will change it's width to fit it's content, or am I missing something in your post?

Comment: i am assuming that the `class` and `id` should be swapped in the example code.. A single id for the `ul` and multiple class for the `li`

Comment: @Rory - the problem i have inline-block is that i want the width to be larger than page width, so you can scroll the images. When i try to apply this it hits the page limit then knocks the following <li> onto the next line spoiling the effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

**html** *minor corrections to your example code*

```
<ul id='fluid_ul'>
    <li><img src=".." /></li>
    <li><img src="..." /></li>
</ul>
```

**jquery**

```
$(window).load(function(){ // once the page has loaded (including images)
    var totalWidth = 0; // a variable to hold the total width of the li elements
    $('#fluid_ul').children().each(function(){ // for each li
        totalWidth += $(this).outerWidth(); // add its width to the total
    }).end().css({width:totalWidth}); // finally revert selection to ul and apply total
});
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry was being lazy with the IMGs in my example. 

The jquery works but applied the width to the children rather than parent: I updated to 

    $(window).load(function(){ // once the page has loaded (including     images)
    var totalWidth = 0; // a variable to hold the total width of the     li elements
    $('.fluid_ul').children().each(function(){ // for each li
    totalWidth += $(this).outerWidth(); // add its width to the total
    })
    $('.fluid_ul').css({width:totalWidth}); // finally apply total to     the ul element});

Which works perfectly I think! Many thanks!!

Comment: @tjh, absolutely right.. sorry for the error.. updating asnwer with the use of `.end()`